# sart function from template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, user-defined-functions

I know that functions can't (shouldn't) be called directly from the template in Django.

But I can't find out how to properly call a simple function. Here is what I would like to do:

On my template I would like to have a hyperlink to paste all relevant information from the template to the clipboard using pyperclip. We frequently have to copy addresses from the database to paste into a word document or an email.

So, copy the data to a String variable and pass that variable to pyperclip.copy() using a hyperlink.

Seems easy enough but I can't find it out.

Comment: You are confusing *server side* and *client side*. Django templates are rendered on the server side and absolutely don't have access to a clipboard on user computer.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include Python code, use a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) in Django.

It sounds like you want something a bit more complex, though. You won't be able to call pyperclip code on the *client* side -- there's just no Python execution environment in place.

Instead, look into using [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) or [Flash](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard) to copy data to the clipboard.